# How to filter []struct with struct?

Tags: go, struct, slice

I define struct like this:

```
type Repo struct {
    Key         string `json:"key"`
    Type        string `json:"type"`
    PackageType string `json:"packageType"`
}
```

And json data is something like

> [
> {
> "key":"docker-sre",
> "type":"LOCAL",
> "packageType":"Docker"
> },
> {
> "key":"docker-test",
> "type":"REMOTE",
> "packageType":"Docker"
> },
> {
> "key":"go-local-dev",
> "type":"LOCAL",
> "packageType":"Go"
> },
> {
> "key":"helm-cloudops",
> "type":"LOCAL",
> "packageType":"Helm"
> }
> ]

What is the best way to get the correct data with different conditions?

```
func getWantedRepos(conf Repo) ([]Repo, error) {}

func main() {
    getWantedRepos(Repo{
        PackageType: "Docker",
    })

    getWantedRepos(Repo{
        Type: "LOCAL",
        PackageType: "Go",
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what do you want in `getWantedRepos` function?

Comment: In Go, the normal way to do this type of filtering is with a for loop and some if statements. There are no fancy filtering functions like in other languages.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `reflect` built-in package to do this. This is the example:

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Repo struct {
    Key         string `json:"key"`
    Type        string `json:"type"`
    PackageType string `json:"packageType"`
}

var someDatas = []Repo{
    {
        Key:         "test",
        Type:        "test",
        PackageType: "test",
    },
    {
        Key:         "test1",
        Type:        "test1",
        PackageType: "test1",
    },
    {
        Key:         "test",
        Type:        "LOCAL",
        PackageType: "test23",
    },
}

func getWantedRepos(conf map[string]interface{}) []Repo {
    var returned []Repo
    for _, val := range someDatas {
        flag := true
        for k := range conf {
            if !reflect.DeepEqual(reflect.ValueOf(val).FieldByName(k).Interface(), conf[k]) {
                flag = false
                break
            }
        }
        if flag {
            returned = append(returned, val)
        }
    }

    return returned
}

func main() {
    var repos []Repo
    repos = getWantedRepos(map[string]interface{}{
        "Key": "test",
    })

    fmt.Println("1 ============================")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", repos)

    repos = getWantedRepos(map[string]interface{}{
        "Type": "LOCAL",
    })
    fmt.Println("2 ============================")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", repos)

    repos = getWantedRepos(map[string]interface{}{
        "Type":        "LOCAL",
        "PackageType": "test23",
    })
    fmt.Println("3 ============================")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", repos)

    repos = getWantedRepos(map[string]interface{}{
        "Type":        "LOCAL",
        "PackageType": "NONE",
    })
    fmt.Println("4 ============================")
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", repos)
}
```

`Output:`

```
1 ============================
[{Key:test Type:test PackageType:test} {Key:test Type:LOCAL PackageType:test23}]
2 ============================
[{Key:test Type:LOCAL PackageType:test23}]
3 ============================
[{Key:test Type:LOCAL PackageType:test23}]
4 ============================
[]
```

I use `map[string]interface{}` instead of Model filtering because if you use a model, for example with `string` attribute, the default value of `string` is "". Even if you didn't initialize the value of the attribute, it will have "" as the default value, and the `reflect` for loop will scan through and try to match model with empty string "", so to avoid that, I use `map[string]interface` so we are more flexible to select attribute we want and vise versa.

I don't know what test case you have, but if you get the datas from database, try to use the `WHERE` instead of doing it like this.

Comment: Great. Thanks for your answer. Not database la.